# How to show custom layout in the center of the screen by using AlertDialog without any backround

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-view

I want to get an alert dialog view when button clicked like this
[image]

my layout file 
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_img"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   // TextView's

</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

    <ImageView
        //  />

    <TextView
        //     />

</FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

However at the end when I clicked button I get this image;

[image]

It has white backround which one I don't want to get it and it is not centered. Can anyone help me? Should I use AlertDialog?

My code for AlertDialog is;

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_congratulations, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this just change the width of your root frame layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_img"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   // TextView's

</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

    <ImageView
        //  />

    <TextView
        //     />

</FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I centered it in this way but how can I remove the white backround? Adding  android:background="@android:color/transparent" doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Hey as you already have centered the content you can set the dialog's window to transparent and then show the dialog to remove that white background.

```
alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
alert.show();
```